# How to display loggedin user name in header - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I was new to WordPress.

Need help to display logged in user name in place of "My Account" in wordpress. Like "Hi, UserName".

Im using woocommerce plugin as my website is related to e-commerce.

Kindly help with detailed steps to solve this query.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Do you have a screenshot to make this question better?

Comment: Yes, i searchd in google and tried short codes like. {your_name} and few many. I was not good in code so Trying to get help via stack

Comment: Seems like this is what you're actually looking for: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196453/displaying-logged-in-user-name-in-wordpress-menu

Comment: i have tried with the steps in this link. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196453/displaying-logged-in-user-name-in-wordpress-menu.

But still i was not able to get the user name in menu item. im getting same #profile_name# in menu

Answer (score 0):

From the WP Codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user):

The call to `wp_get_current_user()` always returns a WP_User object.

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
/**
 * @example Safe usage:
 * $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 * if ( ! $current_user->exists() ) {
 *     return;
 * }
 */
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check if the current user is a logged in user.

```
<?php

// Check if user is logged in
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Get current logged in user details
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $current_user->display_name;
} else {
    echo 'Not logged in';
}

?>
```

Comment: Yeah! For that i got a code from google. But i was not able to display the user name.  Means i dont know how to get the user name in Menu item

Comment: Adding it to the menu is a whole different kind of thing. I would not try to add it to a menu, as this is pretty complicated, and this can be achieved much more easily with the above code. Just paste it somewhere near your menu and style it accordingly.